# DataGridViewComboBoxCell.DataSource being set to null once form is shown

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I'm adding a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to a `DataGridView` during the form's `Load` event handler and setting the DataSource of each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` in the columns. However, once the form is shown, the DataSource of each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` has been set to `null`. Here is the code I use to populate the column and it's cells:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol;

comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboCol.Name = "ComboCol";
comboCol.HeaderText = "Combo Column";
comboCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

this.dgv.Columns.Add(comboCol);

for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // This datatable is actually populated here!
    DataTable myData = PopulatedDataTable(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["info"].Value); 

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell DCC = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    DCC = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgv.Rows[i].Cells["CombolCol"];
    DCC.DataSource = myData;

    DCC.DisplayMember = "Association"; // Association is a column in myData
    DCC.ValueMember = "Association";
}

dgv.Columns["association"].Visible = false;
```

This code does exactly what is expected if I put it in a button that I click AFTER the form has loaded, but when executed during form load the DataSource is cleared. Any suggestions?

Comment: When are you setting the datasource for the DataGridView? try setting the DataGridView datasource before DataGridViewComboBoxCell.DataSource.

Comment: I'm already setting the DataGridView's source before the individual Cells' sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by handling the `DataBindingComplete` event of the datagrid.

Apparently when you populate a datagrid during a form's `Load` event, the data in the datagrid gets rebound. This screwed up the data in the unbound column I was trying to add.

By placing my code above in the `DataBindingComplete` event handler (and disabling the event handler at the beginning and re-enabling it at the end of the event) the columns are added at the appropriate time, and their data isn't scrambled by .NET's foolishness.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I struggled with it for two days and finally the DataBinding Event fixed it.

Here is the complete code to add a combo box cell to some cells on a DataGridView.

```
    private void LoadGrid()
    {
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        dtbl.Columns.Add("FieldNo");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("FieldValue");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtbl.NewRow();
            dr["FieldNo"] = i;
            dr["FieldValue"] = "Name " + i.ToString();
            dtbl.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
        dataGridView1.DataError += new DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(dtgv_ComboDataError);
    }

    private void dtgv_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell dCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                dCmb.Items.Add("Yes");
                dCmb.Items.Add("No");
                dCmb.Value = dCmb.Items[0];
                dataGridView1["FieldValue", i] = dCmb;

                ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1["FieldValue", i]).DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
            }
        }
    }

    void dtgv_ComboDataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        //Nothing needed here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with a very similar problem on a `DataGridView` with a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

The `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataSet` The `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` cell drop down options are to be filled according to the value of another cell of the same row.

Whether I fill in the `ComboBox` Cell Items manually (`DataGridViewComboBoxCell.Items` property) or use DataBinding (`DataGridViewComboBoxCell.DataSource` property), right before entering the `CellFormatting` event handler the values are correct, but as soon as the execution steps in the handler, `myComboBoxCell.Items.Count` goes down to zero.

If the Value of the cell is anything else than `DBNull.Value`, this throws a nasty "System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid".  (Because the `myComboBoxCell.Value` is not contained by `myComboBoxCell.Items`)

My "solution" is more of a *workaround*:
I handle the `DataGridView.DataError` event and fill in the concerned `DataGridComboBoxCell` DataSource within that handler.  Then cancel the exception (`e.ThrowException = False`).

It is a bit too dirty to my liking but it works.